# How to select Top 3 users based on their points

Tags: sql, logic, mysql-workbench, limit

How can I construct a SQL as such that it will cater to the below scenario.

```
UserID | point
 001   |  100
 002   |  99
 003   |  98
 004   |  98
 005   |  97
```

Select top 3 score will be

```
UserID | point
 001   |  100
 002   |  99
 003   |  98
 004   |  98
```

However if i order by point desc and use Limit 3 function it only shows

```
UserID | point
 001   |  100
 002   |  99
 003   |  98
```

where 004 user is excluded in this case.

Comment: Your answer is wrong @DineshDB

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT t1.UserID, t1.point
FROM table1 t1
INNER JOIN
   (SELECT point FROM Table1 GROUP BY point ORDER BY point DESC LIMIT 3) as T2
On t1.point=t2.point
```

OR

```
SELECT Userid,
             point 
             FROM (SELECT    Userid,
             point,
             CASE WHEN 
                @point=t.point THEN
                  @curRank
                ELSE @curRank := @curRank + 1
               END AS rank,
             @point:=t.point AS varpoint
      FROM      Table1 t, (SELECT @curRank := 0, @point=null) r
      ORDER BY  point DESC) x
      WHERE rank<=3
```

Live demo

> http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/abf718/30

Output

```
Userid  point
1   100
2   99
3   98
4   98
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT Y.UserID, Y.point
FROM YourTable Y
JOIN (
    SELECT Distinct point 
    FROM YourTable 
    ORDER BY point DESC 
    LIMIT 3) D ON D.Point = Y.Point
```

Comment: MySQL doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery'

Comment: @NishantGupta, Thanks for the suggestion. Hope we can use `LIMIT` in Derived tables.

Comment: And also I already added the answer using join.

Comment: What if records are like is 100,100,100,99,98 then your answer is wrong I think @DineshDB

Comment: @JayShankarGupta, Now it correct. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: I already did that in my answer @DineshDB